# Child inherit public Base and can use protected constructor

Tags: visual-c++, inheritance, visual-studio-2010

I use MSVC++ compiler. I do not get any erros when I do something like that:

```
class Base {
protected:
    Base() {}
public:
    void f() {}
};

class Child: public Base {
public:
    Child(): Base() {}
};
```

Is this a correct code or there is a features of MSVC++ compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `protected` visibility exists exact to allow derived classes to deal with methods of base. So it is absolutely legal for C++

Comment: I thought that derived classes could deal with methods labeled protected only if they inherit protected. Thanks)

Comment: @wowofbob c++ gives you more. You can even modify visibility of overridden methods for example from protected to public